# ISS error CS0433: name collision

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

In our application we've run into an error numerous times where we get error CS0433, which complains about a name collison in two separate dlls.  This is an ASP.NET app developed in C# using webforms.  It always complained about A TimeLog page.  Anyone have advice for resolving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I found a link in the MSDN that describes this error.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/aa9f90e8-534d-4e74-b656-99187eb3f281/)

To summarize, a naming conflict can happen between the file name of a page (TimeLogTab.aspx) and the class in the code behind (public class TimeLogTab).

The link recommends renaming one of them.  I changed my class to Time_LogTab and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

The error can happen intermittently: I'm using "Publish Web Site" for a VS 2005 Web Application Project with "Delete all existing files prior to publish" and then XCOPY-Deploy to the target IIS folder (which won't delete existing files there). Today I ran into that error for the first time (no new .ascx/.aspx files since weeks), but simply recompiling and redeploying the same project solved the problem.

The only difference: For the 2nd time, I hit the page causing the problem first. Now I'm wondering whether the exact click order really matters or rather whether an arbitrary unlucky click order effectively can crash an ASP.NET site?